# Failing if condition in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

While I am trying to create a new measure, with condition, I am facing the below error.
I am trying to create a dynamic line based on dates on my line graph. For my case, if Sheet[Date] matches to Test[Date] it should return me a value of 100.

[image]

But the error says that a single value for column 'Date' in table Sheet1 cannot be determined.
I also tried to convert the date to week with Weeknum function. But the error still persists.
Does it mean that I can not compare single values in IF condition

If there is a way to compare the dates, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sheet[Date]` and `Test[Date]` are columns, not single values.

You need to specify which single values from those columns to compare. For example, you could compare the maximal values of those columns (within the local filter context):

```
MAX ( Sheet[Date] ) = MAX ( Sheet[Date] )
```

Comment: I did try that part.....but I have a diff comparison to make. I am trying to match the week number of both. My intention is that when the date is taken in consideration it should match the week number. My Axis is labelled by Week Number.

Comment: Then wrap each `MAX` in `WEEKNUM` maybe?